# Issue when I specify an element in my div class

Tags: html, css

*I'm self-teaching myself web design.*

I have a div and wanted to add color to the background of my icon so, my CSS looks like this

```css
.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}

.icon h3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <h3> google </h3>
</div>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

But I expected it to look like this (don't mind the font)

[image]

Why isn't it automatically placing all the h3 elements in the div?

Comment: have you checked the answers?

Answer (score 5):

As a background for your question, you need to know that most html elements have predefined CSS rules that normally include things like `margin`, `padding`, `line-height`, `display` among others. Those definition affect the way elements look and behave by default. So you need to use your browser's developer tools (F12 on most browsers) and inspect the specific element to see what styles are applied. In your specific case, what can be affecting is margin on the `h3` element among other things.

In your specific case what you require can be achieved without a `div` but using only the `h3` element. If you require a `div` it can also be achieved, but it complicates things a little bit since you have to be concerned over two elements instead of one.

What is important to mention is that the usage of fixed widths and heights is not a good idea for such elements as the text can vary in length and it will cause the icon to look broken.

Here's an example of both.

```css
h3.icon {
  width: 64px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.icon {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.icon h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="icon">Google</h3>

<br>

<div class="icon">
    <h3>Google</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you stated isn't the best practice, however, if you really want to implement your way then you must know the following:

**1. Default style sheet and resetting:**

Every browser has its own predefined stylesheet which affects many aspects especially the margin and the padding for all HTML elements, and as a general rule, any website first CSS line should be overriding this default behavior.

There are some ways to override these values, but as a beginner, you can use this:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But this is a bad practice also, kind of performance issues, because using `*` means that you tell the browser that it should get all available HTML tags on earth and apply the style for them, another perspective - actually the formal one - is to mention all used tags in your website instead of `*`:

```css
div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li ...{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**2. Elements display values ([Block-level elements and inline elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp))**

You've used `h3`, `div` which are *block-level elements*, and `h3` tag has its own default font size which will not be fitted - as is - in the specified space for its `div` container *50px * 20px*, so to workaround it you can change the `font-size` of the `h3` to be a percentage of its parent container size.

This is a full snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        * {               /* ! Don't use asterik (*) and replace it with all possible tags  */
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .icon {
            width: 50px;
            height: 20px;
        }

        .icon h3 {
            background-color: yellow;
            font-size: 85%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="gray">
    <div class="icon">
        <center> <!--Center the h3 in the div-->
            <h3> google </h3>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A good idea here would be to recommend the usage of normalize https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: @MihailMinkov Of course it is, but I answered him as he is a beginner, as he grows, he will know better techniques and even more complicated things to handle his requisites.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `background-color` from `h3`
and add it to `.icon`

```css
.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that here you are setting all titles with size *`h3`* with yellow background:

```css
.icon h3 {background-color: yellow;}
```

What you want is to set *`background-color: yellow`* to the entire *`div`*. The result is:

```css
.icon {
   width: 50px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Also, your `div` is a bit small, try setting higher values of width and height in order to better visualize the result.